# C# Join Clause with association table

Tags: c#, linq, join

I have 3 classes : (Personnel, Chirurgien  and Operation)

```
    public class Personnel
{
    [Key]
    public int CodePersonel { get; set; }
    public FullName NomComplet { get; set; }
    public Adresse Adress { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Operation> Operation { get; set; }

}
```

Chirurgien

```
public class Chirurgien : Personnel
{
    public int Nbre_anne_Exp { get; set; }
    public int NoteXP { get; set; }
}
```

and Operation:

```
    public class Operation
{
    public int OperationId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateDebut { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateFin { get; set; }
    public int Duree { get; set; }
    public bool Etat { get; set; }

    public string CIN { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Personnel> Personel { get; set; }

    public Patient Patients { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return CIN;
    }
}
```

And I have also created an association table  "Membre"

```
HasMany(p => p.Personel).WithMany(v => v.Operation).Map(m => {
            m.ToTable("Membre");
                m.MapLeftKey("Operation");
                m.MapRightKey("Personel");
            });
```

How can I get Chirurgien list that have failed Operation (Operation Etat=false) ??

I used this code to return the full Chirurgien list:

```
public ICollection<Chirurgien> NoobDoctors()
    {
        var req = from t in ut.getRepository<Chirurgien>().GetAll()

                  select t;


        return req.ToList();
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: The Linq query is redundant since there are no conditions - just use `return ut.getRepository<Chirurgien>().GetAll().ToList();`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I get Chirurgien list that have failed Operation (Operation Etat=false) ??

You can use `Operation` navigation property with [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534338(v=vs.110).aspx) for filtering:

```
var result = from c in ut.getRepository<Chirurgien>().GetAll()
             where c.Operation.Any(o => !o.Etat)
             select c;
```

Since you have configured `many-to-many` relationship with an implicit junction table, EF will maintain the table (including query joins) for you.

Comment: Hi: I have this exception now Argument null exception was handled on this line :

Comment: where c.Operation.Any(o => !o.Etat) , I have some failed Operations (Etat = false) on my database

Comment: Hmm, this is the drawback of all these repository patterns - one can't see the actual code. So what is `GetAll()`? I was assuming `IQueryable<T>` in which case you cannot get NRE. Is it returning `IEnumerable<T>`? Then change the type or use another method that returns `IQueryable` (the corresponding `DbSet`)